# Using JBusyComponent With JTable In JFrame

Tags: java, swing, noclassdeffounderror, jcomponent, busyindicator

I am getting following excpetion

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/divxdede/text/TimeFormat
at org.divxdede.swing.busy.ui.BasicBusyLayerUI.<init>(BasicBusyLayerUI.java:102)
at org.divxdede.swing.busy.ui.BasicBusyLayerUI.<init>(BasicBusyLayerUI.java:138)
at org.divxdede.swing.busy.JBusyComponent.<init>(JBusyComponent.java:105)
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Gold.IssueToRep1.<init>(IssueToRep1.java:136)
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Gold.IssueToRep1.Instance(IssueToRep1.java:164)
```

I added following Libraries to my project

- jbusycomponent-1.2.2.jar
- SwingX 1.6
- JXLayer 3.0.4
- Jarvis-Commons 0.1

When I added the `JXBusyLayer` Component to my `JFrame` (while wrapping existing `JTable` Component with `JXBusyLayer` Component) using the code below

```
     JBusyComponent<JTable> busytblDetailInfo = new JBusyComponent<JTable>(tblDetailInfo);
     myJFrame.add(busytblDetailInfo);
```

using the [Link](http://code.google.com/p/jbusycomponent/wiki/GettingStarted)!

```
 Edit
```

Added the library Commons-0.2 and the exception disappears.

```
Error 2 !
```

Now No Data is seen on the control(JTable) which is wrapped by JBusyControl.

```
Edit 2
```

Added the code below(by comment of @MadProgrammer) but the problem reamins no data to be viewed.

```
        jFrame.remove(tblDetailInfo);
        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data, header);
        tblDetailInfo.setModel(dtm);
        JBusyComponent<JTable> busytblDetailInfo = new JBusyComponent<JTable>(tblDetailInfo_OrderInfo);
        jFrame.add(busytblDetailInfo);
```

Comment: What are you building with? Netbeans or Eclipse

Comment: I am building using NetBeans

Comment: I added commons-0.2.jar and the exception has disappeared but now  no data is being viewed in the control.

Comment: and also not viewing the busy status in the component . I also added the code    busytblDetailInfo.setBusy(true);

Comment: I assume you set the table model to the table

Comment: yes while loading the data from db

Comment: do i reomve the table tblDetailInfo from frame before adding busytblDetailInfo to the frame

Comment: You should only be adding the table via the bust component.

Comment: @MadProgrammer see my edit2 of the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that it doesn't like being wrapped in a `JScrollPane` which is weird in my opinion :P

(I lie, `BusyComponent` "likes" being added to a `JScrollPane`; but you probably don't want to)

[image]

```
public class TestBusy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestBusy();
    }

    public TestBusy() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new ContentPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ContentPane extends JPanel {

        private JTable table;

        public ContentPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            table = new JTable();
            table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
            model.addColumn("One");
            model.addColumn("Two");
            model.addColumn("Three");
            model.addColumn("Four");
            model.addColumn("Five");
            model.addColumn("Six");
            model.addColumn("Seven");
            table.setModel(model);
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

            JBusyComponent<JScrollPane> busyComponent = new JBusyComponent<JScrollPane>(scrollPane);
            add(busyComponent);

            busyComponent.getBusyModel().setMinimum(0);
            busyComponent.getBusyModel().setMaximum(10000);

            busyComponent.setBusy(true);
            BusySwingWorker<Object, Object[]> worker = new BusySwingWorker<Object, Object[]>(busyComponent.getBusyModel()) {

                @Override
                protected void process(List<Object[]> chunks) {
                    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                    for (Object[] chunk : chunks) {
                        model.addRow(chunk);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    for (int index = 0; index < 1000; index++) {
                        setProgress(Math.round((index / 1000f) * 100f));
                        publish(new Object[]{index, "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"});
                        Thread.sleep(5);
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            };
            worker.execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But can you guide me i want to use in the completed project, i can not rewrite code for 1000s of JTable for a huge project. How can i use BusyComp in this case .

Comment: Find a base component you can wrap the `JBusyComponent` around and add the tables to it.  At the end of the day, you're going to have write the code.

Comment: +1 looks good, that BusyComponent - didn't even know it existed :-)

Comment: @kleopatra I'm very impressed with it my self.  It's doing a lot with `JXLayer` I had ideas of trying.  Need to spend some time going through more throughly

Comment: @MadProgrammer actually i am using Stored procedure to populate my Tables so don't know the actually number of rows to be populated in the tables can you tell i do it for that.

Comment: In this example you show it by adding each cell maually how to populate the  using i mentioned the code in question.

Comment: 1- Set the model to "indeterminate" mode using `BusyModel#setDeterminate(false)`; 2- The basic example I provide SHOULD be the way you go about populating a table model from a background, otherwise it becomes kinda pointless using a background thread